# Scaling edges relatively to the shape

Tags: edges, scale

I'm making a track for a racing game and I want to make borders with a wider area at the top. How can I do this with Blender ? The scaling tool doesn't do what I want to achieve.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: "with a wider area at the top"? Could you please precise what it means exactly? Give an example?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably other ways of doing it but here is at least one. Sometimes you will need to create temporary geometry to instruct the tools what to do. In this case we need to have face normals so the inset tool could be used with depth.

[image]